# Creating one meter line from a point in the direction of a other line using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, linestring

Consider I have a `line_layer` and `point_layer`. I want to create a one meter line at every point in the direction of the line flow.

[image]

Output should be:

[image]

So far I tried:

```
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Points')[0]
line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0]

v_layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=epsg:4326', 'line', 'memory')
pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes(start_layer.fields())
v_layer.updateFields()

line_index = QgsSpatialIndex(line_layer.getFeatures())

for point_feat in point_layer.getFeatures():
    point_geom = point_feat.geometry()
    nearest_ids = line_index.nearestNeighbor(point_geom.asPoint(), 1)
    nearest_geom = next(line_layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(nearest_ids[0]))).geometry()
    start_point = nearest_geom.asPolyline()[0]
    end_point = nearest_geom.asPolyline()[-1]
    line_vector = QgsVector(end_point - start_point)
    point_vector = QgsVector(point_geom.asPoint() - start_point)
    angle = line_vector.angle(point_vector)
    s = point_feat.geometry().asPoint()
    start_x, start_y = s.x(), s.y()
    azimuth_radians = math.radians(angle)
    new_x = start_x + 0.00001 * math.cos(azimuth_radians)
    new_y = start_y + 0.00001 * math.sin(azimuth_radians)
    start_point = QgsPoint(s.x(), s.y())
    end_point = QgsPoint(new_x, new_y)
    seg = QgsFeature()
    seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point]))
    seg.setAttributes(point_feat.attributes())
    pr.addFeatures([seg])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(v_layer)
```

Above script is creating lines at the point but not in the line direction like this

[image]
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the `for` loop as follows:

```
for point_feat in point_layer.getFeatures():
    point_geom = point_feat.geometry()
    nearest_ids = line_index.nearestNeighbor(point_geom.asPoint(), 1)
    nearest_line = next(line_layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(nearest_ids[0]))).geometry()
    
    start = point_feat.geometry().asPoint()
    start_point = QgsPoint(start.x(), start.y())

    angle = nearest_line.interpolateAngle(nearest_line.lineLocatePoint(point_geom))
    end_x = start.x() + 0.00001 * math.cos(math.pi/2 - angle)
    end_y = start.y() + 0.00001 * math.sin(math.pi/2 - angle)
    end_point = QgsPoint(end_x, end_y)
    
    seg = QgsFeature()
    seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([start_point, end_point]))
    seg.setAttributes(point_feat.attributes())
    pr.addFeatures([seg])
```

[image]

Docs: [lineLocatePoint](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a11af1b509c2948401e0bceb005f673ca), [interpolateAngle](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ae4a4d4529237328bbb57d81300e52eed)